# Reading text from a .txt file in Java

Tags: java

I have this piece of code in my project:

```
    String readFile() {
        String pathname = saveDirectory + fileName + ".txt";
        String content = "";
        File f = new File(pathname);
        if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pathname)));
            }
            catch (IOException e) { }
        }
        return content;
    }
```

There are no errors, the aplication runs just right, but the `content` variable never has any text in it and I'm sure that the txt file has text in it!

I've already tried different ways to read the text file (with BufferedReader, Scanner, FileInputStream and FileReader) but none of them worked.

Ps. I'm almost sure that the problem isn't in the `pathname` variable since I've tried to open the file via code (with Runtime) and it opened the right file normally.

Ok, I tried adding the `e.printStackTrace();` but there is still no errors, and it's not missing a `/` between the directory and the fileName, i've already added in the `\\` in the directory variable.

Comment: If you didn't catch and ignore the IOException, you would at least know if it happens, and what the problem is. Don't catch exceptions without handling them. If you can't handle it, throw it. Wild guess, that would easily be confirmed with the message and stack trace of the exception, or with simple debugging: you forgot a `/` between the directory and the file name.

Comment: There may be an error in your try block, but your hiding the stack trace. In the catch block do e.printStackTrace() to check for any errors being thrown, which will log any errors.

Comment: I tried it and still no errors!

Comment: Remove the `if` statement. Don't check if the file exists or it's a directory. Just try to open it. That would be why your content is empty, because it's not finding the file.

Comment: @DavidS, still not a single error :/

Comment: The code should work as written, so something else is wrong, and perhaps it's the file itself. Test it on another text file, one that you know is well formed.

Comment: If you've removed the `if` statement and there are no exceptions being thrown (btw, I would just rethrow it as `throw new IllegalStateException(e)` to be super certain), then yes, there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: You could add something like `System.out.println("file exists")` in your `if` statement just to make sure the file exists and it's not a directory.

Comment: @Austin Sorry for taking long, but I did that and it's printing just right.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The file is programatically created, and it seems normal. Is there any chance that the problem is the "\n" or "\t" in the String I write in it?

Comment: Come on, do some trouble-shooting -- did you test your code on another text file as I've suggested? Does it work? If it does, then likely it's the text file that's at fault. If so, read it as a binary file and analyze the bytes it contains.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I solved the problem, it was a very stupid problem, but it looks like another program was kind of blocking the access of Java to the file, I restarted the computer and it works just fine! Thanks a lot for those who helped!

Comment: Thanks for the update and congrats on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be forgetting the / between the directory and the file name? Print the content of pathname and see.

Or better: debug your code and see what happens.

Comment: Since I could open it using Runtine (that requires the exact same pathname), I think that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're opening the file once (`File f = new File(pathname);`), then trying to read it without using the file object you created. You're probably getting an IOException because `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pathname))` can't open the file while f has it open.

Comment: `new File()` doesn't open a file. A File object represents a Path of the file system. Not an opened file.

Comment: Nope, I add the e.printStackTrace() and there is still no errors :/